# BigQuery Backend Errors during upload operation

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to know what are the possible errors that can arose from Big Query server side during upload mechanism, though the .CSV file that i'm uploading contains perfect data. Can you list out those errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the common errors are:

- Files must be encoded in UTF-8 format.
- Source data must be properly
  escaped within standard guidelines for CSV and JSON.
- The structure of
  records and the data within of must match the schema provided.
- Individual files must be under the size limits listed on our
  [quota/limits page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy).

More information about [BigQuery source data formats](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/import#csvformat).
Check out our [Data Loading cookbook](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/ingestioncookbook) for additional tips.